# Select Latest Records from Customer table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch record of a customer's latest transaction. The query I am trying is this:

```
SELECT 
  food_rate,
  ambiance_rate,
  service_rate,
  cost_rate 
FROM
  tbl_transaction t 
  INNER JOIN tbl_feedback f 
    ON t.fid = f.fid 
WHERE date_time IN 
  (SELECT 
    MAX(date_time) 
  WHERE c_id = 1)
```

The output will be a single row only. But it is giving syntax error.

Comment: Its better to post the error too in your question

Comment: In the last select statement for the WHERE condition you have not written the "TABLE NAME" so it is giving syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT food_rate, ambiance_rate, service_rate, cost_rate 
from tbl_transaction t 
inner join tbl_feedback f ON t.fid=f.fid 
where c_id=1
order by date_time desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  food_rate,
  ambiance_rate,
  service_rate,
  cost_rate 
FROM
  tbl_transaction t 
  INNER JOIN tbl_feedback f 
    ON t.fid = f.fid 
WHERE c_id = 1
ORDER BY date_time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

//you have not written table name in your subquery, i have rewritten the query

```
 SELECT 
  food_rate,
  ambiance_rate,
  service_rate,
   cost_rate 
 FROM
   tbl_transaction t 
 INNER JOIN tbl_feedback f 
   ON t.fid = f.fid 
WHERE date_time IN 
(SELECT 
MAX(date_time) from tbl_transaction
WHERE c_id = 1)
```